# Finding the volume of a solid

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, volume, multiple-integral

How do I attempt the following question, to find the volume of the cylinders:

$$ z=\log x , z=\log y $$ 
and planes -

$$z=0 ,  x+y=2 e , (x>=1)? $$

Is there a way out apart from double integration ?

Comment: Welcome, Deepthi, You can use Latex. Is the edit correct?

Comment: Yes..Thank you. I will try to use latex,i am new here.

Comment: please answer this question guys